# Setting properties for each sub element of each sub element

Tags: c#

I have a set of classes I populate from a 3rd party XML (so I can't really control the structure that much):

```
public class Category
{
    // some properties...

    public Tournament[] Tournaments {get;set;}
}

public class Tournament
{
    // some properties...

    public Match[] Matches {get;set;}
}

public class Match
{
    // some properties...

    public Competitors Competitors {get;set;}
}

public class Competitors 
{
    // some properties...

    public Teams[] Teams {get;set;}
}
```

and so on.

Now, I need on the team level to set some properties from different classes - 
for instance, I need the id of the category, the gender of the tournament etc.

So for now, I have a `foreach` loop that sets the category id for each tournament, and later on in the code I have 3 nested `foreach` loops to copy values from properties of the tournaments to properties the teams.

```
        foreach (var tournament in tournaments)
        {
            foreach (var match in tournament.Matches)
            {
                match.SomeProperty = tournament.SomeProperty;

                foreach (var team in match.Competitors.Teams)
                {
                    team.CategoryId = tournament.CategoryId;
                    team.Gender = tournament.Gender;
                    // and a few more here...
                }
            }
        }
```

Needless to say this is quite an ugly code.
I was wondering if there is a better way to do it, perhaps using LINQ or something like that.

### Update:

For now I have changed my code so that each class has a reference to it's parent. This way I don't need to set any more properties down the chain.
Instead of having `team.CategoryId` I'm now using `team.Match.Tournament.Category.Id`
However, I still have have the same problem, only now it's concentrated in only one place - After the deserialization is completed, I have 4 nested foreach loops - so it looks like this:

```
foreach (var category in MainClass.Categories)
{
    category.FileName = MainClass.FileName;
    foreach (var tournament in category.Tournaments)
    {
        tournament.Category = category;
        foreach (var match in tournament.Matches)
        {
            match.Tournament = tournament;
            foreach (var team in match.Fixture.Competitors.Teams)
            {
                team.Match = match;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice to find a way to avoid these nested loops...

Comment: If you wanna use LINQ that'll be something like this: `tournaments.ForEach(x=> x.Matches.ForEach( y=> y.Competitors.Teams.ForEach(z => { z.CategoryId = .....; z.Gender = ....})));`
But this would be same ugly :P

Comment: @Shakra Yes, I've already tried that. it's even worst :-)

Comment: if you want a clear and readable way to do that, then create some methods at each class, those will set you properties and do inner `foreach`, that's the only way I see.

Comment: It will make the code look cleaner, but IMHO it will not make it more readable. Think about debuging such a thing. You get to a method that does a foreach, and inside sends you to another method that does another foreach, and so on. It's the exact same thing as nested foreach loops, only now it's spread across multiple classes. It does, however, keep separation of concerns, which my code currently doesn't.

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the both inner foreach with the [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx)-LINQ operation.

```
foreach (var tournament in tournaments)
{
    //// We take every team in every competitors to on Enumeration
    foreach (var team in tournament.Matches.SelectMany(match => match.Competitors.Teams))
    {
        team.CategoryId = tournament.CategoryId;
        team.Gender = tournament.Gender;
    }
}
```

Edit:

When you set an property at the first foreach, the SelectMany will not work (because the projection will only hold all teams from the matchs Competitors).

One way to make it a little bit *nicer*, would be to extract a method

```
foreach (var tournament in tournaments)
{
    SetMatchPropertiesFromTournament(tournament);
}
...

private void SetMatchPropertiesFromTournament(Tournament tournament)
{
    foreach (var match in tournament.Matches)
    {
        match.SomeProperty = tournament.SomeProperty;

        foreach (var team in match.Competitors.Teams)
        {
            team.CategoryId = tournament.CategoryId;
            team.Gender = tournament.Gender;
            // and a few more here...
        }
    }
}
```

A nice, small function, which just does only one thing... thats a great thing!

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot some lines in the code sample, I'm also setting some properties of the match. Can I still use SelectMany for this?